# how to do reserve binding in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Due to [seo](/questions/tagged/seo) and some other reason, i want to do reverse binding.

Let suppose this is my html

```
<input data-bind='value: firstName' value="somevalue"/ >
```

And this is my knockout code which is binded with above html.

```
 self.firstName = ko.observable()
```

Now, i want `self.firstName()` should return value which html initialized with i.e  `somevalue`.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/passionateboy/sNSrq/1/

Any chances ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout js initialize the observable value from element content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386396/knockout-js-initialize-the-observable-value-from-element-content)

Comment: check this out http://jsfiddle.net/passionateboy/sNSrq/2/ it is not working. can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the example that @MajorByte posted ([Knockout js initialize the observable value from element content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386396/knockout-js-initialize-the-observable-value-from-element-content)), I've [updated your second jsfiddle to make this work](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9sbm/)

In that linked post, note how Niemeyer says this:

> Note that the property name is in quotes, as the binding supports the observable not existing yet

So I updated your html to reflect that. From this:

`data-bind='textWithInit: firstName'`

to this

`data-bind="textWithInit: 'firstName'"`

Also, the example in that link is reading the innertext of the element. If you want it read the value of the `value` attribute of your element, then you need to change that part of the code as well. From this:

`content = element.innerText || element.textContent;`

to this:

`content = element.value`